# Excel VBA Macro - String to Decimal

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to convert a cell value containing a coordinate to an integer. The string value is "X-324.45", but would like to be able to use this number for an if then loop later.

Msgbox1 shows the string as X-324.45
Msgbox2 shows the string as -324.45
Msgbox3 shows a blank MsgBox

What am I missing here? I would like -324.45 to be a variable I can use for math operations.

Thanks,

```
 Dim YVAL1 As String
 Dim YVAL2 As String
 Dim YVAL3 As Double
 YVAL1 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Value
 YVAL2 = Mid(YVAL1, 1, 10)
 YVAL3 = CDbl(YVAL2)
 MsgBox ("Value1: " + YVAL1)
 MsgBox ("Value2: " + YVAL2)
 MsgBox ("Value3: " + YVAL3)
```

Answer (score 3):

`Mid(YVAL1, 1, 10)` does not remove anything - to read from the 2nd character `Mid(YVAL1, 2, 10)`.

`MsgBox ("Value3: " + YVAL3)` fails because it attempts the arithmetic addition of a non-convertible string to a double - always use `&` to concatenate:

```
MsgBox ("Value3: " & YVAL3)
```

Comment: In fact, if you don't use YVAL2 = Mid(YVAL1, 2, 10), you should get an error on YVAL3 = CDbl(YVAL2) because it's trying to convert a non-numeric string.

Answer (score 3):

```
YVAL2 = CDec(Mid(YVAL1, 2, 10))
```

[image]

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim yval1, yval2
    yval1 = Range("A1").Value
    yval2 = CDec(Mid(yval1, 2, 10))
    MsgBox ("Value: " & yval2)
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know if @Jaberwocky meant to suggest this by using CDec() but it is a good idea to use something like decimal or currency (non-floating point) instead of single or double (floating point) unless the precision is absolutely necessary.